# How to take derivative with respect to a variable of a function of two variables and another function

Tags: partial-derivative

I have a function $f(x-a,y-b\frac{1}{g(x,y)})$. I want to find the partial derivative of this function with respect to $x$. But I am literally lost. Can you give me any insight on the solution?What I could do so far is as follows:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
I am stuck at the point in calculation of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$. Thanks in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Do you know what is the function $f$?

Comment: Is is actually an image.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The function is an image. $f(x,y)$ is the function of an image

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. So you don't have any expression for $f(x,y)$?

Comment: It is exactly the case!